# Weird Model Summary

Tags: keras

I am getting weird model summary using keras and ImageDataGenerator when used with Cats and dogs classification.
I am using Google Colab+GPU.
The problem is model summary seems to throw weird values and looks like loss function is not working.
Kindly suggest what is the problem.

My code is as below

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_dir,
target_size=(150,150),
batch_size=32,
class_mode='binary')

validation_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,target_size= 
(150,150),batch_size=50,class_mode='binary')
history=model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=31,epochs=20,validation_data=validation_generator,validation_steps=20)
```

Model Summary is as below

```
                       Epoch 1/20
        31/31 [==============================] - 10s 241ms/step - loss: 0.1302 - acc: 1.0000 - 
       val_loss: 5.0506 - val_acc: 0.5000
                     Epoch 2/20
       31/31 [==============================] - 6s 215ms/step - loss: 4.4286e-05 - acc: 1.0000 - 
     val_loss: 6.8281 - val_acc: 0.5000
                    Epoch 3/20
       31/31 [==============================] - 7s 212ms/step - loss: 4.6900e-06 - acc: 1.0000 - 
  val_loss: 8.1907 - val_acc: 0.5000
                   Epoch 4/20
       31/31 [==============================] - 6s 211ms/step - loss: 5.8646e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - 
  val_loss: 9.3841 - val_acc: 0.5000
                  Epoch 5/20
       31/31 [==============================] - 6s 212ms/step - loss: 2.0634e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - 
  val_loss: 10.3554 - val_acc: 0.5000
                 Epoch 6/20
       31/31 [==============================] - 6s 211ms/step - loss: 2.8432e-08 - acc: 1.0000 - 
  val_loss: 11.3546 - val_acc: 0.5000
               Epoch 7/20
       31/31 [==============================] - 6s 211ms/step - loss: 1.3657e-08 - acc: 1.0000 - 
  val_loss: 12.1012 - val_acc: 0.5000
              Epoch 8/20
       31/31 [==============================] - 7s 215ms/step - loss: 4.8156e-09 - acc: 1.0000 - 
  val_loss: 12.6892 - val_acc: 0.5000
              Epoch 9/20
      31/31 [==============================] - 7s 219ms/step - loss: 2.9152e-09 - acc: 1.0000 - 
 val_loss: 13.1079 - val_acc: 0.5000
             Epoch 10/20
      31/31 [==============================] - 7s 216ms/step - loss: 1.6705e-09 - acc: 1.0000 - 
 val_loss: 13.4230 - val_acc: 0.5000
            Epoch 11/20
    31/31 [==============================] - 7s 218ms/step - loss: 1.2603e-09 - acc: 1.0000 - 
  val_loss: 13.6259 - val_acc: 0.5000
            Epoch 12/20
  31/31 [==============================] - 7s 218ms/step - loss: 1.7701e-09 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 
 13.7718 - val_acc: 0.5000
           Epoch 13/20
 31/31 [==============================] - 7s 218ms/step - loss: 1.6043e-09 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 
          13.9099 - val_acc: 0.5000
 Epoch 14/20
   31/31 [==============================] - 7s 219ms/step - loss: 3.8831e-10 - acc: 1.0000 - 
   val_loss: 14.0405 - val_acc: 0.5000
             Epoch 15/20
31/31 [==============================] - 7s 216ms/step - loss: 8.9113e-10 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 
           14.1567 - val_acc: 0.5000
                  Epoch 16/20
           31/31 [==============================] - 7s 218ms/step - loss: 8.5343e-10 - acc: 1.0000 - 
                val_loss: 14.2485 - val_acc: 0.5000
              Epoch 17/20
           31/31 [==============================] - 7s 217ms/step - loss: 2.8638e-10 - acc: 1.0000 - 
              val_loss: 14.3410 - val_acc: 0.5000
                  Epoch 18/20
             31/31 [==============================] - 7s 218ms/step - loss: 5.3467e-10 - acc: 1.0000 
              - val_loss: 14.4225 - val_acc: 0.5000
                   Epoch 19/20
             31/31 [==============================] - 7s 217ms/step - loss: 4.5269e-10 - acc: 1.0000 
            - val_loss: 14.4895 - val_acc: 0.5000
                         Epoch 20/20
                  31/31 [==============================] - 7s 216ms/step - loss: 3.4228e-10 - acc: 
                1.0000 - val_loss: 14.5428 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `model.summary()` instead of `history = model.fit...`